# Add extra header information in codeigniter email

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, html-email

I would like to send some extra information on the emails which is sent from codeigniter library. Is there any way to configure or add this?

I want to categorize all the outgoing mail from my site. I need to include sendgrid category header for tracking.

Answer (score 11):

The CodeIgniter email class doesn't let you manually set headers.  However you could change this by extending it and adding a new function that allows you to set the sendgrid headers.

See the "Extending Native Libraries" section of the CodeIgniter manual:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
Here's what the code in your new email class might look like.

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
     }

    public function set_header($header, $value){
        $this->_headers[$header] = $value;
    }
}
```

You'd then be able to set headers using your new email class like this:

```
$this->email->set_header($header, $value);
```

This page will explain what headers can be passed to SendGrid:
http://sendgrid.com/docs/API%20Reference/SMTP%20API/

Comment: I have used this method successfully to add new headers to outgoing mails. However when I use it, it no longer pays any attention to the email.php config file which holds the smtp settings. Is there any way to do both?

Comment: You are right @Gortron, when you use this class, you lose the settings from config/email.php; the way I solved it, is to copy the entire CONSTRUCT() function from the original class, don't do parent::__construct(); not sure why that's happening, but when I copy the full constructor, it works. I'll make another answer below, because the comments are too short for the whole code :)

Comment: I've updated the code to correctly pass the $config var (credit to @suvozit for their answer). This should mean that the config from email.php will work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Alright, I just want to improve the best answer here. 
Credit goes to @Tekniskt, and the only difference here is that the settings you might have in /application/config/email.php are ignored, which hurts, especially if you are using custom STMP settings.

Here's the full code of the class MY_Email.php I've improved from the answer above:

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

public function __construct($config = array())
{
    if (count($config) > 0)
    {
        $this->initialize($config);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_smtp_auth = ($this->smtp_user == '' AND $this->smtp_pass == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->_safe_mode = ((boolean)@ini_get("safe_mode") === FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    log_message('debug', "Email Class Initialized");
}

// this will allow us to add headers whenever we need them
public function set_header($header, $value){
    $this->_headers[$header] = $value;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

I did my test, and it seems now /config/email.php is included and settings are passed properly.

Cheers and thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `$config` parameter

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email
{
  public function __construct(array $config = array())
  {
    parent::__construct($config);
  }

  public function set_header($header, $value)
  {
    $this->_headers[ $header ] = $value;
  }
}
```

Set custom header as

```
$this->email->set_header($header, $value);
```