# How to set extra information to email header while sending email to GMAIL

Tags: php, gmail

I am using CodeIgnitor email library to send email. I want to add "EmployeeId:" to email header and then send email to gmail email address.

How can I add that information to header ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the mail() function?

```
$header = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail('mail@gmail.com', 'Subject', 'Message', $header);
```

Update:

In CodeIgnitor you need to extend the EMail class with your own set_header method. From here you can call the hidden _set_header() method.

You may take a look at these exact explanations and examples:

- https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/168377/#1005186
- http://thisisleon.co.uk/2011/05/29/sendgrid-and-codeigniter/

Comment: Nope, I am using email library of CodeIgnitor. I want to add "EmployeeId: <employee_id>" in email header while sending email to GMAIL

Answer (score 0):

It depends on class / function you are using for sending e-mail.

Using simple `mail` function you can do that by setting `additional_headers` parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

but I would recommend you to send emails with `SwiftMailer` (http://swiftmailer.org/) - playing with headers is as simple as:

```
// adding new text header
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('Your-Header-Name', 'the header value'); 

// changing value
$subject = $message->getHeaders()->get('Subject');
$subject->setValue('new subject');
```

More on: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html

Comment: Actually, I am using email library of CodeIgnitor. I want to add "EmployeeId: <employee_id>" in email header while sending email to GMAIL

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter mailer everything is well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9062483/751387

$this->email->set_header($header, $value);

Comment: I tried it, but not working. It is not showing "employeeid" tag in output of imap_headerinfo or imap_fetch_overview

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter email library does not allow to add additional header informations. To do this, we can create a custom library class by inherit the system email class as follows:

save MY_Email.php in application/libraries/ folder

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_custom_header($header_key, $header_value) {
        $this->_set_header($header_key, $header_value);
    }
}
/* End of file MY_Email.php */
```

This library class inherit codeigniter email class and add a method add_custom_header() with two argument named header key and header value and club this to header information for the email.

usage:

```
$this->email->add_custom_header($header_key, $header_value);
```